# Select first city name with respective length order alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql

I think a follow-up question based on the problem from HackerRank, and wonder if it is possible to solve by SQL.

Sample Input

Let's say that CITY has four entries: DEFG, ABC, PQRSER, and WXY

Sample Output

```
ABC 3
DEFG 4
PQRSER 6
```

I was wondering if I can use SQL to ordered length of city and city name alphabetically with the respective lengths. And if there are options for the same length city (e.g., ABC, WXY), I just want to choose the first city name, because it comes first alphabetically. Thanks!

Comment: So if two cities exist of the same length, ABC and XYZ, you do not want to see XYZ in the list?

Comment: @DanielGale Yes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are correct then, aggregation is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an aggregation here by length.  The subquery below identifies the alphabetically first name for each character length of the city.  Then, we join to this subquery to leave us with the city names we want, ordered ascending by length.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(city) AS first_city
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(city)
) t2
    ON t1.city = t2.first_city
ORDER BY
    CHAR_LENGTH(t1.city);
```

### Demo

Note: If you really just want the city names, then the following would suffice:

```
SELECT MIN(city) AS first_city, CHAR_LENGTH(city) AS length_city
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(city)
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(city)
```

But in real life, more typically, you would want the entire record back, in which case my first query is a better option.

Comment: Thanks, but this code did not return the column of CHAR_LENGTH(city).

Comment: I wonder if I can use only one query or that would be a problem? 
    SELECT MIN(city) AS first_city, CHAR_LENGTH(city)
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CHAR_LENGTH(city)
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(city);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CITYNAME, LEN(CITYNAME) AS WORDLENGTH FROM <YOUR TABLE> ORDER BY CITYNAME, LEN(CITYNAME) ASC;
```

Comment: LEN() is used in SQL Server, but MySQL uses Length()

Comment: I think his question is about SQL not MySql :-)

Comment: The question is tagged mysql.

Comment: He tagged both sql and Mysql :-)

Comment: Looks like we both omitted that cities need to be grouped by size anyway :). Better luck next time.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sure just ORDER BY length of the city name then by city name.

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY Length(city), city;
```

Comment: Nice. I had the most of it, forgot the 'city' name as secondary order.

Comment: What you first wrote was not the answer to the question, you know it!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve the result with subquery and aggregation.

**In MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, LENGTH(city) cityLength
FROM test
ORDER BY LENGTH(city), city) A
GROUP BY cityLength;
```

See a [**DEMO on SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eea5c/2).

Comment: `it works` ... this query won't run on any other database, nor on certain versions of MySQL.  Also, there is no guarantee that this will always pick the first city name.  Doing `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is generally bad.

Comment: It will always pick the first alphabetically sorted city per the length. I don't really care if it won't run on any other database. The OP should adapt it for any other database.